# The Diophantine equation system

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, maple, wolfram-alpha

I deal with the following equation system:
$$k \left(k^4+5 k^2 m+5 m^2\right)=1 \\ k^2+4 m=l^2$$

Mathematica and Maple show that the solution of this system for the ${k,m}$ pair can not be represented in radicals, while the solution for $m,l$ can be.

The question I have is the following may I relay on Mathematica or Maple or this is irrelevant?

And if the Mathematica and Maple are correct may I assume that this system has no rational solutions based on the fact that the solutions can not be represented in radicals?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Diophantine generally means integer solutions, in this case, the first equation forces $k=1,m=0$ and then $l=\pm 1$. Are you searching for rational solutions instead ?

Comment: Sorry yes I am looking for rational solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ k(k^4 + 5k^2m +5m^2) = 1 \\ k^2 + 4m = \ell^2$$

If $k$ and $m$ are integers, then $k = k^4 + 5k^2m + 5m^2 = \pm 1$.

If $k=1$, we get $1 + 5m + 5m^2 = 1 \iff 5m(m+1)=0 \iff m \in \{0, -1\}.$

Then $k^2 + 4m = \ell^2$ becomes 
\begin{cases}
   \ell^2 = 1 & \text{If $m = 0$} \\
   \ell^2 = -3 & \text{If $m = -1$} \\
\end{cases}

If $k=-1$, we get $5m^2 + 5m + 2 = 0,$ which has no integer solutions.

So we get $(k,\ell,m) \in \{(1,1,0), (1, -1, 0)   \}$

### Rational Solutions?

If you let $\ell = x+y$ and $k=x-y$, then $k^2 + 4m = \ell^2$ becomes 
$m = xy$ and $k(k^4 + 5k^2m +5m^2) = 1$ becomes $x^5-y^5 = 1$, which has no nontrivial rational solutions.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the question was if this has solution in **rationals** if the Mathematica and Maple say that it has no solution in radicals for $k,m$ pair?

Comment: Yes, after a more careful search, I finally found the word rational. It's "Diophantine" that threw me off. But thank you for being civil when you pointed out my error.

Comment: This substitution in $x,y$ is almost magical, can I know what motivates it, ? This is an interesting technique.

Comment: @zwim $4m = \ell^2 - k^2=(\ell-k)(\ell+k)$ suggested $\ell+k = 2x$ and $\ell-k = 2y$...

Comment: So this is kind of lucky that $k(k^4+5k^2m+5m^2)$ simplifies this much ? (I guess it was part of problem's author's twisted mind then to hid stuff that way).